# Invalid value Error when try to navigate to another view is sapui5 app, using routing parameters for segment "{RoutingObjectName}"

Tags: routes, navigation, sapui5, sap-fiori

Getting this error in console:

Uncaught Error: Invalid value "{"Appointment":"239290003","Vendor":"IRTo dfj POI LTD T/A RT MEMO TO Order(PTY","VendorID":"2342","CourierDescr":"Test Couriers","Court":"OBC"}" for segment "{DocumentID}".
at B (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3485), :7484:7413)
at String.replace ()
at Object.y [as interpolate] (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3485), :7484:7670)
at R.interpolate (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3485), :7484:4999)
at constructor.getURL (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3485), :1185:44)
at constructor.getURL (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3485), :1206:156)
at constructor.navTo (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3485), :1213:34)

Answer (score 0):

Navigation parameters are mapped to the URL. Therefore this should be the keys you need in the target view to request this object from the odata model.

If that's a strange app, not following guidelines store the object in a model attached to the component. But routing becomes a bit pointless with his method.

If it's an object being created; store it in a json-model linked to the component. Hence there is no need to pass anything.

Answer (score -2):

Getting this error while navigating from one sapui5 view to another because the object I am passing through the

`this.oRouter.navTo("toProductList", {`
`StoreID: aItemResults.StoreID,`
`DocumentID: btoa(JSON.stringify(oDetail))` 
`});`

Value oDetail.Vendor
"Vendor":"IRTo pdf POI LTD T/A RT MEMO TO Order(PTY" contains a backslash and it is invalid.

So just need to use this method `btoa(JSON.stringify(oDetail))` it would change the entire string into base64 and in another view, you need to decode it using the below method.

`JSON.parse(atob(e.getParameter("arguments").DocumentID))`

The issue would be resolved by encoding and decoding the string.